# First one-to-one with new boss: should I present my CV?

Tags: interviewing, promotion, politics, careers

Our new Head of Department started two weeks ago. He is organising one-to-one meetings with everyone to get to know us and figure out how the department currently operates. So far so good. I have my meeting with him tomorrow - should I print my CV to take with me?

He wants to get to know us, I want to present as someone organised, best foot forward and keen to progress (I am five years in, no promotion, would like to either move up or move on). If I show him my (v strong) CV will this help?

EDIT
Thanks for all your responses. I went to the meeting with bullet points and demoes of work prepared - but not CV. This was the right call, and not only did it mean that meeting went well, it also meant I was very well prepared for a job interview elsewhere that I had later in the day. Thanks all, really appreciate your answers.

Comment: When did you start, i.e. how long have you been with the organisation? Is your CV up to date?

Comment: Been here 5yrs, CV up to date as I've been actively job hunting.

Comment: Assuming that the "move up or move on" aspect is also a conversation you'd like to have with this manager in the extremely near future I'd probably recommend against showing him your CV. The chance of that being taken the wrong way or escalating a discussion is way too high.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't, from the question I can see you've been there five years so either you're presenting him with 5 year old information about you and your skills or if you've updated your CV it will look like a passive-aggressive way of saying that you are currently job hunting! Probably not the footing you want to start your working relationship with your new manager on!

What I would do however is put together some bullet points/notes on what your skills, responsibilities and recent (~6-12 months sounds about right) accomplishments in the role are. Possibly some suggestions for your future professional development there as well. Sort of like a "cheat sheet" about you (in a professional sense obviously).

Don't go overboard on length or detail and I probably wouldn't be quite as full-on self-promoting as a CV would be. This will show you as organised and the other good things you want to get across and let you recap all the good things you've been doing at the organisation before they got there.

Comment: @user75476 Happy to help!

Answer (score 7):

If you have already been hired, your manager will likely only want to know about your current work and what you're like as a person. He should also hopefully know what your role involves, even if he hasn't spoken to you directly. The CV might be overkill (though you could maybe have it on hand and wait for him to suggest it).

What might be helpful, if you have access to a laptop or a portfolio of some sort, you could give him a demonstration of some of the work you are currently doing. Don't just tell him what you have done and what you're doing, show him. That would likely present you as the organised and prepared type.

Comment: "*Don't just tell him what you have done and what you're doing, show him.*" That's what your CV should contain in the first place. Very few people in very few professions benefit from having an actual portfolio. Between having your CV to hand to go over some of your accomplishments, or giving an entire presentation or demo I know which I would call overkill.

Comment: Thanks also useful. I think I will prepare bullet points of recent job activities and achievements, as motosabu suggested, have a CV to hand in case it comes up (but probably won't use it) and have a couple of work examples to show - this is relevant as I work in visual media